# Displaying user avatar foreach post in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm actually working in a little forum project, everything is fine till I was stuck in a problem.
I want to display the user Image in front of every post he creates.
I have a table called discussion and another called users and each one of them contains the "user_id" column, but I couldn't figure out how to link them.

Comment: You're talking about Laravel Eloquent Relationships:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

As you've described, a User entity associated with a Discussion entity in a "one to one" relationship, as you can further read here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Does that make any sense?

Comment: the master id in the `users` table named `user_id`? or you by mistake typing `users` table and you mean another table to tell you the right way to link

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to know about relation ship between the database table. then you need to learn about eloquent relationship on laravel docs.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships